# Radio Button Value not passed in other activity Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I've an issue with a `RadioButton`. I tried to pass the value of a `RadioButton` but didn't work for me.

Even `button.setSelected(true)` didn't work.

**Activity 1:**

```
    private EditText FirstName;
    private EditText LastName;
    private EditText MobileNo;
    private Button BtnNext;
    private ProgressBar  progressBar;
    private String selectedtype="";
    private RadioGroup Gender_grp;
    private RadioButton btn_gender;
    private RadioButton btn_gender1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_form);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        LastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        Gender_grp=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        btn_gender=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_male);
        btn_gender1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_female);
        MobileNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        BtnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_regform);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_form);
        btn_gender.setSelected(true);
        Gender_grp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                if(checkedId==R.id.btn_male)
                {
                    selectedtype=btn_gender.getText().toString();
                }
                else if(checkedId==R.id.btn_female)
                {
                    selectedtype=btn_gender1.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });

        BtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Firebase ref=new Firebase(config_firebaseurl.FIREBASE_URL);
                String fname=FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
                String lname= LastName.getText().toString().trim();
                String phno=MobileNo.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Information Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(registration_form_handler.this, means_of_transport_handler.class);
                i.putExtra("fname", fname);
                i.putExtra("lname", lname);
                i.putExtra("sex", selectedtype);
                i.putExtra("phno", phno);
                startActivity(i);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity 2:**

```
String getfname=getIntent().getStringExtra("fname");
String getlname=getIntent().getStringExtra("lname");
String getgender=getIntent().getStringExtra("sex");
String getphno=getIntent().getStringExtra("phno");
String license_no = licenseno.getText().toString().trim();
transport.setFirstName(getfname);
transport.setLastName(getlname);
transport.setGender(getgender);
transport.setmobileNo(getphno);
ref.child("means_of_transport").push().setValue(transport);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**In the database, the result is:**

```
gender=""
```

Both `RadioButton` can be selected but I want one at a time.

**XML file:**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/btn_male"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/btn_female" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: shouldn't radio buttons be direct child of radio group

Answer (score 0):

Your `RadioButton` is inside group, try to get the selected id from the `RadioGroup`.

Solved code:

```
private EditText FirstName;
private EditText LastName;
private EditText MobileNo;
private Button BtnNext;
private ProgressBar  progressBar;
private String selectedtype="";
private RadioGroup Gender_grp;
private RadioButton btn_gender;
private RadioButton btn_gender1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_form);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    LastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);

    Gender_grp=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    btn_gender=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_male);
    btn_gender1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_female);

    MobileNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    BtnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_regform);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_form);
    btn_gender.setSelected(true);

    BtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //code changes here
            int id = Gender_grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            Gender_grp = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
            selectedtype = Gender_grp.getText().toString();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Firebase ref=new Firebase(config_firebaseurl.FIREBASE_URL);
            String fname=FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
            String lname= LastName.getText().toString().trim();
            String phno=MobileNo.getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Information Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(registration_form_handler.this, means_of_transport_handler.class);
            i.putExtra("fname", fname);
            i.putExtra("lname", lname);
            i.putExtra("sex", selectedtype);
            i.putExtra("phno", phno);
            startActivity(i);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private EditText FirstName;
private EditText LastName;
private EditText MobileNo;
private Button BtnNext;
private ProgressBar  progressBar;
private String selectedtype="";
private RadioGroup Gender_grp;
private RadioButton radioBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_form);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    LastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    Gender_grp=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    MobileNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    BtnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_regform);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_form);
    btn_gender.setSelected(true);

    BtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Firebase ref=new Firebase(config_firebaseurl.FIREBASE_URL);

              // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int radioBtnId = Gender_grp..getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            selectedtype = radioBtn.getText().toString().trim();
            String fname=FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
            String lname= LastName.getText().toString().trim();
            String phno=MobileNo.getText().toString().trim();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Information Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(registration_form_handler.this, means_of_transport_handler.class);
            i.putExtra("fname", fname);
            i.putExtra("lname", lname);
            i.putExtra("sex", selectedtype);
            i.putExtra("phno", phno);
            startActivity(i);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Get data in other activity as you done.

Note: Any variable will be declare as start with small latter.